# Segmentation fault (core dumped) codelite ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, codelite

I am trying to use the bubble sort method to organize a matrix.
I am getting an error that says Segmentation fault (core dumped).
I am programming on a Virtual Machine using Ubuntu and Codelite. Hope you can help me out.

This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int tam, comp, var;

    printf("Ingrese el tamano del array que va a crear:\n");
    scanf("%d", tam);

    int arr[tam];

    printf("Ingrese los elementos del array:\n");
    for(int i=0; i < tam; i++){
        printf("Elemento arr%d", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);        
    }

    for(int j=0; j < tam; j++){
        for(comp=0; comp<tam; comp++){

            if(arr[comp]<arr[comp+1]){

                var=arr[comp];
                arr[comp]=arr[comp + 1];
                arr[comp + 1]=var;               
            }
        }            
    }

    printf("La matriz en orden descendente es:\n");

    for(int i=0; i < tam; i++){

       printf("%d ", arr[i]);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Look at this: `scanf("%d", tam);`

Comment: `arr[comp+1]` might occurs out-of-bounds error.

Comment: you should not use a variable for array size declaration. (->arr[tam])

Comment: @krpra: Why not? That's a variable length array and perfectly legal C since the C99 standard.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then  use the `gdb` debugger

Comment: @MOehm Yeah I did not mean that it is wrong.It is legal but sometimes it makes confusion,one must be careful if one use.

Comment: When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the second and following parameters must be pointers, not the name of a variable.  Regarding: `scanf("%d", tam);`  Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &tam ) ) { fprintf( stderr, "input of 'tam' failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: Please state which line is causing the seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `for( int comp=0; comp < tam; comp++ )`  inside this loop, reference is made to `arr[comp+1]`.   When the value `comp` reaches its limit of `tam-1`, then that reference will be accessing beyond the end of the array: `arr[]`.   Remember, in C, the valid indexes to an array are: 0...(number of elements in array-1).  Accessing beyond the end of the array is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @YaatSuka,  your suggestion is not correct, the second and following parameters must be pointers to where to place the scanned value and `arr[i]` is the contents of the entry in arr[], not the address of `arr[i]`.  so, for the referenced statement, the OPs code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles (gcc on linux)
2. performs the desired operation
3. does not seg fault
4. corrects the problems listed in the question comments
5. properly checks for I/O errors and properly routes error messages to `stderr`
6. keeps data closely related to where it is used.
7. makes use of appropriate horizontal spacing for readability
8. documents why each header file is being included

Suggest using `puts()` rather than `printf()` for output that does not contain any formatting.

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf(), scanf(), fprintf(), stderr
//#include <math.h>  <<-- contents not used, so do not include
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main( void )
{
    int tam;

    printf( "Ingrese el tamano del array que va a crear:\n" );
    if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &tam ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for 'tam' failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful


    int arr[tam];

    printf( "Ingrese los elementos del array:\n" );
    for( int i=0; i < tam; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Elemento arr%d", i+1 );
        if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &arr[i] ) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for array entry %d failed\n", i+1 );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful.
    }

    for( int j=0; j < tam; j++ )
    {
        for( int comp=0; comp < (tam-1); comp++ ) // note correction and data scope limiting
        {

            if( arr[comp] < arr[comp+1] )
            {
                int var       = arr[comp];  // note data scope limiting
                arr[comp]     = arr[comp + 1];
                arr[comp + 1] = var;
            }
        }
    }

    printf( "La matriz en orden descendente es:\n" );

    for( int i=0; i < tam; i++ )
    {
       printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
}
```